# Unable to resume activity: not allowed to start service Intent, app is in background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-9.0-pie

I haven't been able to reproduce this crash myself but I see a lot of crashes lately in Crashlytics. The crash only happens on Android 9 and greater:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
    Unable to resume activity {co.whitesmith.flicks/co.whitesmith.flicks.media.audio.AudioPlayerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.devbrackets.android.playlistcore.start_service cmp=co.whitesmith.flicks/.media.service.MediaService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{63e190 u0a221 TPSL bg:+3h19m42s918ms idle change:idle procs:1 seq(2385,2385,2385)}`
```

The stack trace:

```
android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1616)
android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1571)
android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:669)
arrow_right
com.devbrackets.android.playlistcore.manager.BasePlaylistManager.play (BasePlaylistManager.kt:298)
co.whitesmith.flicks.media.audio.AudioPlayerFragment.startPlayback (AudioPlayerFragment.kt:231)
co.whitesmith.flicks.media.audio.AudioPlayerFragment.restartAudio (AudioPlayerFragment.kt:201)
co.whitesmith.flicks.media.audio.AudioPlayerFragment.updateCurrenPlaybackInformation (AudioPlayerFragment.kt:401)
co.whitesmith.flicks.media.audio.AudioPlayerFragment.onResume (AudioPlayerFragment.kt:118)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume (Fragment.java:2649)
```

I don't understand this crash. Why isn't it possible to start a service in the `onResume()` method?
Isn't supposed to be in the foreground when the activity enters the Resumed state?

Comment: I call the super before the playback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug! In Android 9+, there's a race between the app UID turning foreground and the activity being resumed.

This is a workaround from Google:

> The issue has been addressed in future Android release.
>
> There is a workaround to avoid application crash. Applications can get the process state in `Activity.onResume()` by calling
>   `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` and avoid starting Service if
>   the importance level is lower than
>   `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`. If the
>   device hasn’t fully awake, activities would be paused immediately and
>   eventually be resumed again after its fully awake.

However there's a simpler workaround that delays the service being started until the app fully turned foreground:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> startService(...), 100);
```

Comment: I guess delaying the start service for 100ms doesn't guarantee that the app is fully turned foreground

Comment: @ricardopereira You can schedule a repeating task and check process state, repeat the task until you get `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`.

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been fixed, and whether it is available to use. Otherwise does anyone have a consistently working workaround for this?

Comment: @rideintothesun Based off crash reports on my app, it looks like its no longer an issue on Android 12+

Answer (score 4):

What @frogatto explained in code:

```
        //temporary bug fix for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110237673
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (runningAppProcesses != null) {
            int importance = runningAppProcesses.get(0).importance;

            if (importance <= ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)
                //startService(...);
        }
```

Comment: Legend! Check worked perfectly.